# Unable To Build Solution In Visual Studio Getting error 'child node 2 exited prematurely'

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2012, build

I am having an issue with building the solution with visual studio 2012, I am getting an error Child Node 2 exited Prematurely.

I googled it and found this link

[error MSB4166: Child node exited prematurely. Shutting down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7916687/error-msb4166-child-node-exited-prematurely-shutting-down)

but I have enough Physical Memory and Virtual memory in my system.

This is the diagnostics report.

> UNHANDLED EXCEPTIONS FROM PROCESS 2370776:
>   ===================== 9/23/2014 9:22:35 AM Microsoft.Build.Shared.InternalErrorException: MSB0001: Internal
>   MSBuild Error: We must not have both the assembly name and the
>   assembly file/path.    at
>   Microsoft.Build.Shared.ErrorUtilities.ThrowInternalError(String
>   message, Exception innerException, Object[] args)    at
>   Microsoft.Build.Shared.AssemblyLoadInfo.Create(String assemblyName,
>   String assemblyFile)    at
>   Microsoft.Build.Shared.AssemblyLoadInfo.FactoryForTranslation(INodePacketTranslator
>   translator)    at
>   Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.NodePacketTranslator.NodePacketReadTranslator.Translate[T](T&
>   value, NodePacketValueFactory`1 factory)    at
>   Microsoft.Build.Logging.LoggerDescription.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.INodePacketTranslatable.Translate(INodePacketTranslator
>   translator)    at
>   Microsoft.Build.Logging.LoggerDescription.FactoryForTranslation(INodePacketTranslator
>   translator)    at
>   Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.NodePacketTranslator.NodePacketReadTranslator.TranslateArray[T](T[]&
>   array, NodePacketValueFactory`1 factory)    at
>   Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.NodeConfiguration.Translate(INodePacketTranslator
>   translator)    at
>   Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.NodeConfiguration.FactoryForDeserialization(INodePacketTranslator
>   translator)    at
>   Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.NodePacketFactory.PacketFactoryRecord.DeserializeAndRoutePacket(Int32
>   nodeId, INodePacketTranslator translator)    at
>   Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.NodePacketFactory.DeserializeAndRoutePacket(Int32
>   nodeId, NodePacketType packetType, INodePacketTranslator translator)
>   at
>   Microsoft.Build.Execution.OutOfProcNode.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.INodePacketFactory.DeserializeAndRoutePacket(Int32
>   nodeId, NodePacketType packetType, INodePacketTranslator translator)
>
> ## at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.NodeEndpointOutOfProcBase.PacketPumpProc()

Comment: I don't see "child node 2", I see "Internal MSBuild Error: We must not have both the assembly name and the assembly file/path."

Comment: @RegEdit: The specified error is shown in the out error output window of visual studio. Diagnostics file doesn't have anything like that.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, entirely different cause. I am using a SyncFusion Carousel control from a NuGet package. Turns out the Carousel cannot have an explicitly defined SelectedIndex in XAML. Very odd error code, seems like I should have gotten a runtime error with a message, "Failed to set property SelectedIndex".