# Error in Visual Studio 2015: error MSB4166: Child node "3" exited prematurely. Shutting down

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, build, msbuild

I build source code with Visual Studio VS2015 win10 64 and i get error in MSBuild_failure.txt in temporary folder.

```
*error MSB4166: Child node "3" exited prematurely. Shutting down. Diagnostic information may be found in files in the temporary files directory named MSBuild_*.failure.txt*
```

I uninstall Visual Studio and i reinstalled it but it still the same problem.

I'm very grateful if one can help me and give me a solution.

Comment: It seems to be the same problem. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7916687/error-msb4166-child-node-exited-prematurely-shutting-down)

Comment: Did you try to create a new wpf project in VS2015 and then built it ,has the same error?

Comment: Hi Sarah, any update about this issue? Did my answer help you handle this issue?

Comment: Hi Perry, thanks for your respone.                                                                                          I try to create a new wpf project in VS2015 and I built it but i found the same error.

Comment: Please check if my answer's suggestions help you handle the issue. If it helps, do not forget to accept it, if not, please feel free to let us know 0:)

Answer (score 0):

> Error in Visual Studio 2015: error MSB4166: Child node “3” exited
> prematurely. Shutting down

The issue is complex and I guess the issue is caused by your project itself or your computer environment.

Please try the following suggestions:

**1)** clean all nuget caches by running command `nuget.exe locals all -clear` under **Tools**-->**NuGet Package Manager**-->**Package Manager Console**

**2)** close VS2015, create a new **System Environment Variable** called **MSBUILDDISABLENODEREUSE** and set it value to `1`.

**Then**, restart your project to test again.

**3)** **Instead**, you could use MSBuild command line to build your project.

Open `Developer Command Prompt for VS2015` and type:

```
msbuild xxx\xxx.csproj -t:build -p:Configuration=Debug -nodeReuse:false
```